# How to get user's high resolution profile picture on Twitter?

Tags: twitter

I was reading the Twitter documentation at https://dev.twitter.com/overview/general/user-profile-images-and-banners and it clearly states that:

> Alternative image sizes for user profile images You can obtain a
>   user’s most recent profile image, along with the other components
>   comprising their identity on Twitter, from GET users/show. Within the
>   user object, you’ll find the profile_image_url and
>   profile_image_url_https fields. These fields will contain the resized
>   “normal” variant of the user’s uploaded image. This “normal” variant
>   is typically 48px by 48px.
>
> By modifying the URL, you can retrieve other variant sizings such as
>   “bigger”, “mini”, and “original”. Consult the table below for more
>   examples:
>
> Variant   Dimensions  Example URL normal  48px by
>   48px  http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/2284174872/7df3h38zabcvjylnyfe3_normal.png
>   https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/2284174872/7df3h38zabcvjylnyfe3_normal.png
>   bigger    73px by
>   73px  http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/2284174872/7df3h38zabcvjylnyfe3_bigger.png
>   https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/2284174872/7df3h38zabcvjylnyfe3_bigger.png
>   mini  24px by
>   24px  http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/2284174872/7df3h38zabcvjylnyfe3_mini.png
>   https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/2284174872/7df3h38zabcvjylnyfe3_mini.png
>   original  original    http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/2284174872/7df3h38zabcvjylnyfe3.png
>   https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/2284174872/7df3h38zabcvjylnyfe3.png
>   Omit the underscore and variant to retrieve the original image. The
>   images can be very large.

Twitter API's response is like this for my own account:

```
{
  ....
  "profile_image_url_https" = "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/559415382457348097/qSYxxIAo_normal.png";
  ...
}
```

That image URL works, but it's too small. I need the highest resolution available. I do exactly what Twitter says, and omit the `_normal` suffix, and try this URL:

https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/559415382457348097/qSYxxIAo.png

But it's not found. Is Twitter docs outdated or am I missing a point?

**UPDATE:** I've tried with a few friends' profiles and most of them seem to work, and removing any suffixes and adding `_400x400.[jpg|png]` also seems to work, but it's undocumented and unreliable, so I really doubt that I should be using this undocumented API in production.

**UPDATE 2:** I've refreshed my user object as Twitter also states in case of outdated images, but nothing has changed.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

for me the "workaround" solution was to remove the "_normal" from the end of the string

Check it out below:

- Low res image:  https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/636894769742897152/frlgaWB8_normal.jpg
- Hi res image:
  https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/636894769742897152/frlgaWB8.jpg

Comment: I was contemplating some APIs. This was just a simple workaround.
Thanks @Silviu St.